# how to assign a jenkins global environment variable from inside an sh script

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins global environment variable assigned, is it possible to override it from inside the sh"""    """ script?

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        MYIMAGE=""
    }
    stages {
        stage('CREATE IMAGE'){
            steps {
                script {
                    if ((BRANCH_NAME == "DEV" )) {
                        script {
                               sh """  
                               if [[ $BRANCH_NAME == "dev" ]]; then
                                   env.MYIMAGE="image1";
                               elif [[ $BRANCH_NAME == "TESTING" ]]; then
                                   env.MYIMAGE="image2";
                               else
                                   env.MYIMAGE="image3";
                               fi
                               echo ${env.MYIMAGE}
                               """
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so I want to set the envrionment variable conditionally from inside the script, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think no way to do as you said.

Firstly, the Jenkins pipeline global `env` allow you insert new environment, but overwrite existing environment.

Secondly, the `sh` step can't evaluate Groovy expression within Bash.

If you accept use general Groovy variable, but environment you can do as following:

```
// declare MYIMAGE to be a global variable of your pipeline
// then you can access it anywhere in your pipeline

// Don't define MYIMAGE in environment{}
def MYIMAGE = "<you can put default value here or give empty value>"

pipeline {
   stages {
     stage {
        script {
          def cmd = '''
             if [[ $BRANCH_NAME == "dev" ]]; then
                IMAGE="image1"
             elif [[ $BRANCH_NAME == "TESTING" ]]; then
                IMAGE="image2"
             ...
             fi
             echo ${IMAGE}
          '''
          MYIMAGE = sh(returnStdout: true, script: cmd).trim()
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: this answer should be accepted. Thanks to share it with us. –